# Standardize inline chord symbol formatting

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I love asking, answering, and reading questions/answers about chords, but lately I've noticed it is sometimes when a question/answer talks about chords, notes, and keys all the letters kind of run together. Today I was just reviewing an [old question I answered](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/21905/is-i-v-a-stronger-progression-than-i-v) and it took me a few read throughs to figure out what what a chord, what was a note, and what was a key. Here is an excerpt from that post:

> The reason V to I and V to i progressions are so strong is because V leads to I(i). In C major a G (with the notes G B D) would go to a C (with the notes  C E G). As you can see the G is common in both chords and the B in the G (also known as the leading tone) goes to a C by going up a half step (m2) and the D goes up a whole step(M2) to the E.

Just to have the chords stand out I decided to bold them which changes the passage above to:

> The reason V to I and V to i progressions are so strong is because V leads to I(i). In C major a **G** (with the notes G B D) would go to a **C** (with the notes  C E G). As you can see the G is common in both chords and the B in the **G** (also known as the leading tone) goes to a C by going up a half step (m2) and the D goes up a whole step(M2) to the E.

The chords now pop out a little more, but I'm not sure this is the best formatting for them or if there is a standard that exists somewhere. It would be nice to have some kind of site standard. I'll suggest a few, but my knowledge of html and what is possible is limited.(For example I think bold and next font size up would be good, but can't figure out how to do it using the HTML SE allows)

1. (just bold) The notes C, E, and G make a **C** which is V in the key
   of F major.
2. (bold & italicized) The notes C, E, and G make a ***C*** which is V in the key
   of F major.
3. (emphasized) The notes C, E, and G make a *C* which is V in the key
   of F major.

Comment: For the next font size use `###text`; `##text` for the bigger and `#text` for the biggest

Comment: @Shevliaskovic isn't that just for headings?

Comment: Yes, but it makes the font bigger :P

Comment: I think this is the only way. Look at [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Another option is to in some way incorporate if it's a major or minor triad. It makes it clear what is referred to, at the cost of some more letters.